# Mule soap request wrapping spml contents

Tags: java, web-services, mule, spml

I have a task wherein I am supposed to wrap the `spml` content in `soap` request message. How can I do that at the `inbound-endpoint`. I mean mule should receive a request which has `spml AddRequest`.
I have tried using `@webserviceprovider`, however it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to be as descriptive as possible. Questions like "it doesn't work" are discouraged. Please [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for advice on asking questions. Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you tried